# jQuery animation jumping before animating on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, animation, position

I'm creating a sliding carousel by making a container div with `overflow:hidden`, and an image div within it that I'm trying to move by animating the `left` position. Like so:

The HTML

```
<div id="placeholder">
    <div id=carousel>

         <img src="wideimagestitched.png">

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#placeholder {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px
    overflow: hidden;
}

 #carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
        }
```

the jQuery:

```
$("#rightbutton").click(function(event){

event.preventDefault();
$("#carousel").animate({"left": "-500px"}, 1000)

});
```

This works fine and smoothly in Firefox, but in chrome the `carousel` div jumps about 200px to the left before animating, as it should, to the right. I've slowed it right down, and can see the inline styles being applied, and yup - it's jumping backwards 200px or so in there, before animating.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: these codes works fine in chorme 22 check your chorme version but I think your problem is in other code not chrome!

Comment: thanks... I'm using Chrome 22 too, but defo jumping. Can't see anything in code that would do this. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine see this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/MzNZX/)

Comment: Yup, that works fine... But my code isn't. perhaps it could be do do with the fact that I'm starting the image in the middle, to allow left/right clicks.  i.e.Left is set to "-916px" and the animation takes it to (rightclick) "-1860px" and (leftclick) "0px"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with fouc,your jquery will work after document.ready state,so any content that the browser reads from the dom will be displayed without jquery in action.Put your concerned code in visiblity:hidden till the dom has been read properly then at document.ready unhide, you can see the following example where i faced a similar problem

[fouc example](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/06/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_22.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using hardware acceleration with this plugin:
http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

Works really smooth